# Keras training and testing accuracy are not equal for the same input

Tags: deep-learning

I used Keras to learn COIL-20 dataset.  During the training, I got the following result:

```
Epoch 1/5
1440/1440 [==============================] - 8s 6ms/step - loss: 1.0584 - acc: 0.7972
Epoch 2/5
1440/1440 [==============================] - 5s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0911 - acc: 0.9799
Epoch 3/5
1440/1440 [==============================] - 5s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0228 - acc: 0.9944
Epoch 4/5
1440/1440 [==============================] - 5s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0161 - acc: 0.9979
Epoch 5/5
1440/1440 [==============================] - 5s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0416 - acc: 0.9896
```

The training accuracy is **0.9896**.  But when I test the model using the same data.  I got the **0.58056** accuracy.  I expected to get the same numbers for training and testing because I used the same data.  What have I done wrong?

The code is available from Google colab
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1XOXtoibs1DG8y3AJZSYUzLnWF_6vxemf

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055289/kerass-model-fit-is-not-consistent-with-model-evaluate

Comment: Thank you very much.  I removed BatchNormalization and Dropout layers.  The testing results is now a little bit more accurate.   Training 0.9743  Testing 0.9958  Both on the same data set.